# How to change default WAS liberty server port 9080 to other port number in RAD?

Tags: java, websphere, port, application-server, websphere-liberty

When I am using WAS Liberty profile V8.5 beta, I can not find anywhere to change default service port 9080 in RAD, I tried to add httpendpoint section in server.xml, liberty server reports configuration update successful, but got failure when running web application.

Anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in the beta which prevented some port changes from being preserved when the server was restarted. There is a forum thread discussing the issue with the cached port value, and the answer is to start the server with the --clean option (from the command line), there is an equivalent checkbox available when you start the server via the tools.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14770100

I would start there.